# How to space out x-ticks on bar graph, and scale y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code that creates a small dataframe of various countries and a corresponding score value:

```
import pandas
import numpy 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pandas.DataFrame(data = ["Norway", "Denmark", "Iceland", 
"Switzerland", "Finland", "Netherlands", "Canada", "New Zealand", 
"Sweden", "Australia"], columns = ["Countries"])
df["Score"] = [7.6, 7.55, 7.50, 7.45, 7.40, 7.35, 7.30, 7.25, 7.20, 
7.15]
```

I then create a bar graph using matplotlib :

```
bars = df['Countries']
height = df['Score']
plt.bar(bars, height, align = "center", alpha = 0.5)
plt.ylabel('Happiness Score')
plt.title('Happiness by Country')
plt.show
```

I am unsure on how to do 2 things:
1) space out the country names of the x-axis so that they are not crossing each other 
2) scale the y-axis differently, so that all of the scores don't seem so close to each other

Comment: Use `plt.ylim(7,8)` to scale

Comment: @RockyLi: Wonderful suggestion. For completeness sake, I added your suggestion to the answer below

Answer (score 3):

You can simply rotate the labels by some angle of your taste to avoid the overlap. Other way would be to use a widely spaced x-positions for your bars. However, since the country names are long and unequal in length, I wouldn't suggest this.

EDIT: For completeness sake, I am adding Rocky Li's suggestion for the scaling of the y-axis.

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylim(7, 8)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect for the x-axis, Rocky Li answered the Y scaling part

Comment: @Steel: I see now. Glad to help.